# Saving common aggregations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have a Mongo aggregation I know that I will use frequently, for example, finding the average of a dataset.

Essentially, I want someone to make an API for the database such that someone could type db.collection.average() in the mongo shell and get the result of that function, so that someone without much knowledge of the aggregation framework would easily be able to get the average (or result of any complicated aggregation function I create). What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of MongoDB 3.4, you can create [views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/index.html) that wrap a defined aggregation pipeline. Sounds like a perfect fit for your use case.